# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (T-SQL)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

[image]

How to connect or make relationship with the following tables:

First table is called `Case` :

```
CaseID,
Name,
Number of hours
```

Second table is called `professor case`:

```
professorID,
CaseID
```

Third table is called `professor`:

```
professsorID,
name,
Lastname
```

This is how it should look, I don't know how to connect them

[image: second]

[image: se]

Comment: Why do you do you want to "connect" them?

Comment: i  need to Calculate GPA by Item ID
Shown in the result column PredmetID and the sum score, grouped by column in the table PredmetID StudentPredmet
Calculate the average score for each student

Comment: You should add that to the question along with some sample data in your tables and what the expected output is with that data. What is a GPA?

Answer (score 2):

If your asking how to `join` the `professor` and `Case` tables, here goes:

```
SELECT 
  professor.name,
  professor.Lastname,
  case.Name,
  case.NumberOfHours
FROM
  Professor professor
    INNER JOIN ProfessorCase pc ON pc.professorId = professor.professorId
    INNER JOIN Case case ON pc.CaseId = case.CaseId
```

This gives you all the cases attached to a professor.

Comment: I get an error in second table : Create table Case (ProfessorID // do i need to put Primary key or just int ?  CaseID int )

Comment: @user2016064 I would have a primary key defined as the ProfessorID.